Zookeeper unimplemented error after upgrading to jdk 17
Objective
I am trying to migrate my application from jdk 11 to 17.
Issue
After migrating to jdk17, i got the error mentioned here (Unable to canonicalize address error) - Zookeeper connection error.
As per the solution mentioned in the same link, i upgraded my zookeeper client version from 3.4.16 to 3.5.6. However, a new error popped as mentioned in log image below. I have upgraded curator framework/recipe from 4.0.2 to 4.2.0.
I understand that Curator 4.2.0 is compatible with Zookeeper versions 3.4.x and 3.5.x. Curator Compatibility. Also, my zookeeper server(ensemble) is still in version 3.4.x. I am not quite sure why it is still causing the issue.
Possible Changes
1.) Change the zookeeper client/curator to any other version.
2.) Change the zookeeper server version to match the client version(A bit difficult as dev ops manage it)
Contraints
I cannot revert my zookeeper client to 3.4.x, otherwise will get the same error-  Unable to canonicalize address again.
Error Logs
Current Pom
1.) Changed zookeeper client to 3.8.x and curator to 5.x.x got the same error.
2.) Changed zookeeper client to 3.5.6 and curator to 4.2.0, still got the same error.

error logs are not present , only pom screenshots are present, plz check
